# Sync Framework - consistency unit

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I was reading [sync framework glossary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902816.aspx) when I found the following statement:

> **consistency unit** : The minimal unit of consistency. Because all changes that have the same consistency unit are sent together, synchronization can never be interrupted when only part of a consistency unit is applied.

My question is: If connection falls when one consistency unit is being applied, what does happen?

I am suspecting that I am facing a problem related to this. I am simulating the following scenario: I am doing sync through a WCF service when internet falls. So, sync is interrupted and in other opportunity I repeat synchronization. When I do it, I get violation of primary key conflict. More specifically:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AREAPERIODOAGRONEGOCIO'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AreaPeriodoAgronegocio'. The duplicate key value is (7). The statement has been terminated.

Comment: is the PK violation caused by a re-sync or is it really a valid conflict occurring? try using batching and setting applicationtransactionsize so you can resume where it stopped.

Comment: Yes, it was because re-sync after previous sync falls because connection error. I stopped to raise exception when this kind of conflict occurs, and it worked. I have to research about batching, I didn't understand well yet what is it... Thank you very much!